# FileMaker 11 JDBC - How to SELECT the current system date?

Tags: filemaker

In Oracle, I can `SELECT sysdate FROM dual` to get the current system date/time.

How can I do the same accessing a FileMaker database via the JDBC driver?

*Note: "Don't use FileMaker" is unfortunately not an option.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an unstored calc field that calls Get ( CurrentHostTimeStamp ) and then include that field as one of your selected fields.

(Make sure you configure the field's options so that FileMaker does not store the calculation results - unless you want the date/time of when the field was added...)

Comment: Nice, that works and feels cleaner than selecting from an explicit table.  Had to make sure FM is not caching the calculation though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know FileMaker, but maybe the standard (ANSI SQL) expressions `CURRENT_DATE` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` work?

So something like

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM whatever
```

Edit: 
Another thing to try could be the standard JDBC escape function:

```
SELECT {fn CURTIME()}
FROM whatever
```

Comment: The issue is the "whatever" table name.  I can't rely on a particular application table being there, so I need to find out what the equivalent "dual" table is in FileMaker.

Comment: Maybe FileMaker allows a select without a table? (like e.g. PostgreSQL)

Comment: No such luck - SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP doesn't work, but it works when I give a known table name.  I just need a known "system" table name now...not sure that's available in FM.

Comment: Why don't you simply create a DUAL table then?

Comment: I want this script to work when run against any FileMaker database.

Comment: Must be a JDBC issue because normally (e.g. from a plug-in) "SELECT CURRENT_DATE" works just fine.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to settle for specifying a known table name.